# Value of last non empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula in Excel:

```
LOOKUP(2;1/(A:A<>"");ROW(A:A))
```

To find the position of the last non empty cell using this tutorial https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell

However, I would like to use it in VBA however I cannot create a similar code.

```
nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (Range("A:A") <> ""), Range("A:A").Row)
```

But it's not working, I get a type mismatch. How could it be achieved?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/894903/excel-macro-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column

Answer (score 2):

```
 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' or whatever sheet you are working on
 nextrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that standard way wouldn't be using of worksheet function. For me it would utilising the way I would find last non empty cell manually in Excel - CTRL+arrow down.

In case the last non empty cell is also first one:

```
Sub Find_first_non_empty_row()

Dim Last_value As String


'select first cell in the range with values
Range("A1").Select

'go to the end to the last cell with value (same as CTR + arrow down) and select the cell
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

'get value of the selected cell
Last_value = Selection.Value
```

But in the link you shared I see that there are some empty rows splitting the ranges with values - so the first non-empty cell is not necessarily the last. In that case one lecturer on Udemy was suggesting starting at the end and going up:

```
Sub Find_last_non_empty_row()

Dim Last_value As String


'select lasst cell in the sheet
Range("A1045876").Select

'go to the first cell with value up (same as CTR + arrow up) and select the cell
Selection.End(xlUp).Select

'get value of the selected cell
Last_value = Selection.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way of fining the last used cell in a Column A.

> Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End (xlUp)

But it returns the last visible cell in Column A.

`Range.Find()` will return the actual last non-empty cell in a range or `Nothing` if all the cells are empty.

> Columns("A").Find(What:="*", _
> LookAt:=xlPart, _
> LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
> SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
> SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
> MatchCase:=False)